# Renaming object keys destructuring with a symbol or a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was just wondering if there is a way to rename object key values with a symbol or a number as the new name. I know you can rename an object like this:

```
let totalValues = {3V: 2.09, fg%V: 3.02}
const {'3V': threev, 'fg%V': fgV } = totalValues;
totalValues = {threev, fgV };
```

is there a way to rename the values like this with it working?

```
let totalValues = {3V: 2.09, fg%V}
const {'3V': 3PM, 'fg%V': FG%} = totalValues;
totalValues = {3PM, FG%};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create object like `from:to` name

```js
const totalValues = { '3V': 2.09, 'fg%V': 3.02, do_not_rename: 1 };
const renameFromTo = {
    '3V': '3PM',
    'fg%V': 'FG%',
};

const result = Object.entries(renameFromTo).reduce(
    (acc, [from, to]) => ({ ...acc, [from]: undefined, [to]: acc[from] }),
    totalValues,
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`%` is an invalid symbol when declaring a variable name, however it is legal in JSON object naming.

You can rename and deconstruct like this, so long as the variable you are renaming to is legal.

Numbers are valid in variables, as long as the are accompanied by a non-numeric value.

```js
let totalValues = {'3V': 2.09, 'fg%V': 3.02};
let { 'fg%V': fgv } = totalValues;
console.log(fgv); // 3.02
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

In javaScirpt naming variables has specific rules, you can't start a variable name with a number or use special character except `_`, so while destructing you are actually creating variables so you must follow the rules. *[Check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)*